# RVM works, Ruby gems installed, but not accessible with require

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

Here’s my problem:

```
➜  ~ rvm current
ruby-2.2.1
➜  ~ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

➜  ~ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]
➜  ~ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
bundler (1.10.6)
coderay (1.1.0)
domain_name (0.5.24)
http-cookie (1.0.2)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (2.6.1)
netrc (0.10.3)
plaid-ruby (0.1.2)
plist (3.1.0)
pry (0.10.1)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rest-client (1.8.0)
slop (3.6.0)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
➜  ~ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'plaid-ruby'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- plaid-ruby
    from /Users/richardburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/richardburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/richardburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require `plaid`, not `plaid-ruby`. The file you require doesn’t necessarily have the same name as the gem, although it’s often the case that it does.

In fact from the [Rubygems page for `plaid-ruby`](https://rubygems.org/gems/plaid-ruby) and the [Github page it links to](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-ruby) it looks like it is an old version of the Plaid client, [and you should be using the `plaid` gem](https://github.com/plaid/plaid-ruby/blob/master/plaid.gemspec#L6).

Comment: Thanks. That’s where I got confused :)